# SolrCloud Scalability on millions of updates daily

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

In current architecture we use shard based db model[MYSQL] and one Solr server[non-cloud mode] is dedicated with 32 GB of memory to hold 1 shard data[max of 10 million items]. Application need to perform full re-indexing every day for each shard due to business requirements on computation logic. In order to perform full re-indexing, we have created temp solr servers and **swap** the indexed data to solr servers. This approach is well working and we have not faced any issues.

Since we are moving out of relational data model to nosql model, we are planning to go with Solr Cloud as shard based model is going away. I am very concerned that how Solr cloud sustain for 200 million updates everyday. **During these updates, the same solr servers are also responsible to serve millions of get request for business operations.**

- Number of Solr servers : 30
- Memory/RAM on each server : 32 GB
- Size on each server : 4 - 10 millions items [4 to 20 GB]

Would someone suggest us, Will SolrCloud sustain with 200 million item updates everyday while serving get requests?

Answer (score 1):

When updating a document, SOLR will mark the old version as deleted, and insert the new version. Deleted documents won't be found by any query (a *:* query will return only non-deleted docs), but they still consume disk space, and *they do slow down your search* (by blowing up the bitmaps of filter queries).

A SOLR index is broken into segments of rather different sizes. Once in a while some segments will be merged, which also eliminates the deleted docs from these segments.

Problem is, though, that the larger a segment becomes, the rarer it is merged, and the more deleted docs it will accumulate.

We run a SOLRCloud setup with 60 mio docs in the main collection, split into 6 shards, 30-50 GB total collection size on disk, ca. 30 mio updates per day; each cluster consists of two 8-core 128 GB RAM servers.

Our solution to this problem was to make sure that each shard in our setup is smaller than 10 GB. For that, we have three SOLR instances running independently on each server (on ports 8983, 8984, and 8985). With each shard below 10 GB, SOLR's mechanism for merging segments works quite well for us.